# Como salvar o dia de hoje no banco?

Tags: php, mysql

Como faço para salvar automaticamente o dia no banco de dados sem precisar passar ele quando for adicionando o produto ou seja cada vez que você adiciona um produto ele automaticamente já grava a data do computador em um atributo da tabela.

Comment: salvar o dia me lembrou algo como superman salvando o planeta num dia qualquer...  salvar data seria mais adequado.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Como disse o @WallaceMaxters basta adicionar `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` no campo referente à data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  data TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

O `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` pode-se usar se também quiser que ao **atualizar** o registo a data também seja atualizada.

Comment: Ostentou, hein!

Comment: Ao fazer um insert não esqueça de inserir o `date`=NOW () que significa agora

Comment: @Megatron Do jeito que o Jorge sugere, não precisa.

Comment: Dessa maneira, o bd "auto-insere"  a data local na hora em que for executado o insert.

Comment: pode parecer bobo mas timestamp tem um problema. Termina em 2038. Ressalto que a resposta nao estaá incorreta. É uma mera observação.

Answer (score 7):

Leonardo, você pode utilizar a função `getdate()` do `PHP`.

Exemplo retirado do *`phpnet`*:

```
<?php
  $today = getdate(); 
  print_r($today);
```

O resultado obtido em `$today` é semelhante á este:

```
Array
(
    [seconds] => 40
    [minutes] => 58
    [hours]   => 21
    [mday]    => 17
    [wday]    => 2
    [mon]     => 6
    [year]    => 2003
    [yday]    => 167
    [weekday] => Tuesday
    [month]   => June
    [0]       => 1055901520
)
```

Comment: +1 não conhecia essa função

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não vejo essa função sendo muito utilizada também, gostaria de saber o motivo rs...

Comment: prefiro evitar essas funções antigas... não está errado o uso mas quem conhece o php e seu historico, sabe que funções como essa entra em modo “deprecated” num futuro próximo.. um indício forte disso foi a implementação da classe DateTime() há alguns anos.

Answer (score 5):

No banco de dados, vai na coluna Default e coloca `current_timestamp()` ou `now()`.

O tipo do campo deve ser `timestamp`, `date` ou `datetime`. Depende da sua circunstância.

Comment: eu devo colocar isto no predefinido certo? mas esta dando erro ALTER TABLE `produtos`  ADD `data` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;

Comment: não use o campo data com nome data. pois "data" é uma palavra reservada do mysql.

Comment: Execute isso: `ALTER TABLE produtos ADD COLUMN data_reg TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp();`

Comment: +1 acho uma ótima ideia fazer isso porque você não precisa de controlar a inserção na coluna.

Answer (score 5):

Na minha opnião, você deveria salvar a data completa de hoje. Se precisar filtrar o dia, use funções específicas do `MYSQL` para isso.

Define seu banco como `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` no campo referente à data.

Answer (score 2):

Supondo um campo do tipo DATE/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP há duas formas.

1 - Pelo próprio Banco de Dados
  Utilize funções como now() `UPDATE tabela SET campo_data = now()` // Tambem pode usar CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, pois now() é apenas um apelido para o CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ou 
  Defina o campo com `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` e não passe nenhum valor no INSERT

2 - Pelo PHP
   Utilize funções de data como date() para gerar uma string no formato YYYY-MM-DD e coloque na instrução SQL
   Ex.: `$dt = date('YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s');`

Obs.: Se por acaso o campo for do tipo CHAR/VARCHAR/TEXT (não imagino os motivos para isso, mas...) é obrigatório usar a forma 2

Answer (score 0):

Crie um campo do tipo datetime, ele irá ficar com o formato americano: Y-m-d H:i:s (Ano-mês-dia Hora:Minutos:segundos):

Então, para inserção, execute a query assim:

```
  INSERT INTO tabela
  (
   campo1, campo2, seu_campo_datetime
  )
  VALUES (
  'valor1', 'valor2', now()
  );
```

E para atualização:

```
  UPDATE tabela
  SET campo1='valor1',
      campo2='valor2',
      seu_campo_datetime=now()
  WHERE 1;
```

E se precisar consultar (pode formatar a saída), faça assim:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(seu_campo_datetime,'%d/%m/%Y') as DataBanco 
from   tabela;
```

Se preferir usar uma data default, tem que ser no formato de timestamp:

```
ALTER TABLE produtos 
ADD COLUMN data_reg TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
DEFAULT current_timestamp();
```